# TypeError: Cannot read property '#<HTMLInputElement>' of undefined

Tags: javascript

There are two `<input type="text">` form elements and a `button` than I'm attempting to attach event handlers to via `.forEach()`. Upon trying to access each element the following error is being raised:

- `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '#<HTMLInputElement>' of undefined`

However, if I hard code the event handlers individually to each one of those elements the subject error is not raised. What is going on for this to occur?

**JS**

*Fails*

```
const login_container = document.querySelector(".login_form_container");
const username_field = document.getElementById("id_login_username");
const password_field = document.getElementById("id_login_password");
const post_login = document.getElementById("post_login");

login_container.addEventListener("mouseout", function(event) {
  this.classList.add("shift");
})

[post_login, username_field, password_field].forEach((widget) => {
    widget.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
      login_container.classList.remove("shift");
    })
})
```

*Passes*

```
post_login.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    login_container.classList.remove("shift");
})

username_field.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    login_container.classList.remove("shift");
})

password_field.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    login_container.classList.remove("shift");
})
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="login_form_container shift slide">
      <form class="login_form">
      {% for field in login_form %}
        {{ field }}
      {% endfor %}
        <button id="post_login" class="login_button" type="button">Access</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: The solution appeared to be selecting the entire form for the mouseover event instead.

Comment: In your case "this" represents the window object, not the element. If still you want to use "this" keyword then use ES6 arrow function in callback.

Answer (score 2):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lsnhgj4/) shows a warning explaining what's happening.

You don't have any semicolons after your `.addEventListener` calls, which means the JavaScript parser interprets the array literal as an indexing operator on the result of `addEventListener`.

And since `post_login` is not a valid index into `undefined` (the return value), it throws a `TypeError`.

```js
login_container.addEventListener(...)[post_login, ...].forEach(...)
```

You can fix it by simply adding semicolons after each call.

[image]